# How can I include the column type in the title when printing a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I combine the functionality of just printing a pandas DataFrame with DataFrame.dtypes.

For example instead of just doing a print(df) and getting:

```
      animal age
0  alligator 12
1        bee 13
2     falcon 1
3       lion 15
4     monkey 14
5     parrot 44
6      shark 100
7      whale 200
8      zebra 14
```

I would get:

```
      animal (string) age (int64)
0  alligator          12
1        bee          13
2     falcon          1
3       lion          15
4     monkey          14
5     parrot          44
6      shark          100
7      whale          200
8      zebra          14
```

I am following a tutorial online and would like to see the structures of the tables before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note Pandas dtypes do not necessarily reflect Python built-in types. For instance, there is no such thing as `str` dtype. In Pandas strings are stored in `object` dtype series, which represent pointers to arbitrary objects.

You can use a list comprehension and assign to columns:

```
df.columns = [f'{col} ({col_type})' for col, col_type in zip(df, df.dtypes)]

print(df)

  animal (object)  age (int64)
0       alligator           12
1             bee           13
2          falcon            1
3            lion           15
4          monkey           14
5          parrot           44
6           shark          100
7           whale          200
8           zebra           14
```

For your use case, simply printing `df.dtypes` should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` and `df.dtypes` to rename your column headings to tuples:

```
df.columns=list(zip(df.columns, df.dtypes))
```

Be aware that rather than 'string', the dtype of string columns is 'object'